# solve$ \int \frac{(1+e^{-5x})^{\frac{1}{3}}}{e^{5x}}dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{(1+e^{-5x})^{\frac{1}{3}}}{e^{5x}}dx$$

$u=1+e^{-5x}$

$du=-5e^{-5x}dx$

so the expression is $\int \frac{u^{\frac{1}{3}}}{-\frac{1}{5}}du=-5u^{\frac{1}{3}}du$?

Comment: It's a good choice of $u$-substitution.  Not sure what your Question is though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int \frac{(1+e^{-5x})^{\frac{1}{3}}}{e^{5x}}dx &= \int (1+e^{-5x})^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{-5x}dx \\ &= \int (1+e^{-5x})^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{-5}{-5}e^{-5x}\right)dx \\ &=-\frac{1}{5}\int \color{red}{(1+e^{-5x})^{\frac{1}{3}}}\color{blue}{(-5e^{-5x})dx} \\ &\stackrel{sub}= -\frac 15\int \color{red}{u^{1/3}}\color{blue}{du}\end{align}$$

Comment: why do I need to $\frac{-5}{-5}$ step? I can just multiple by $-\frac{1}{5}$ do "remove" the $-5$ addition

Comment: Sure.  As long you've got a $-5$ factor *and* a $-\frac 15$ factor it amounts to the same.